# Prepend beginning to object name and set text in java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to pick up java quickly and looking for a way to set the text of a number of labels in my java app.

What I have is a java app that starts\stops\checks status of windows services. I have a method, which is passed an array of these service names and each of these services has a corresponding label that contains it's status. For example, DummyService1 is contained in the array and there is a label called txt_DummyService1. My method (short version) does the following

```
public static void Checker(String Array[])
{
//check status of DummyService1
"txt_"+DummyService.Text = "started";
}
```

I realize that this isn't the way that you do this, but could anybody help me out with the best way to do this?

Comment: is this java language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to generate a "variable" name from a `String` in this manner.  Yes, you might use reflection, but that already rasies questions about the quality of the design.

Instead.  Place each label into a `Map` keyed by it's name.

```
private Map<String, JLabel> labelLookup = new HashMap<>(25); // Instance variable.
```

In you constructor (or where ever you build your UI), add each label to the `Map`.

```
/* Other UI code */
labelLookup.put("DummyService1", txt_DummyService1);
```

Now, when you need to do you changes, simply look up the label by it's name

```
// You had better have a VERY good reason for making this static...
public void checker(String services[])
{
    for (String service : services) {
        JLabel label = labelLookup.get(service);
        if (label != null) {
            label.setText("Started");
        }
    }
}
```

For example...

Comment: I posted the version of code that I found to work, but as you said it uses reflection and I'm seeing that that has its own disadvantages. I'll give this a shot and see if I fair any better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for something more like the following

```
public static void Checker()
{
    try
    {
        Object Instance = getClass().getDeclaredField("txt_DummyService").get(this);
        Method m = Instance.getClass().getMethod("setText",String.class);
        m.invoke(Instance,"started");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    //exception handling
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate variable names at runtime since these are only available to the compiler. One solution to your problem is to keep a `Map<String, JLabel>` (assuming you are using `JLabel` and not some other component) to associate a name with each `JLabel`. I'm sure there are several other possible solutions depending on the exact design of your code.